# EC2 network burst credit balance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I know my usage of *network* credit balance? I have a t4g.small instance and periodically I face timeout issues on the networking services hosted there.

As it stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html):

> An instance receives the maximum number of network I/O credits at
> launch. If the instance exhausts its network I/O credits, it returns
> to its baseline bandwidth. A running instance earns network I/O
> credits whenever it uses less network bandwidth than its baseline
> bandwidth.

But in the CloudWatch I see CreditBalance for CPU and EBS only:

[image]

How do I monitor Network Credit Balance?

Comment: The same document you quoted tells you how to monitor this stuff. Take another look. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html#monitor-instance-bandwidth